# Cross Domain Login into Linux Systems

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos, powerbroker

I have below setup in my office

2 AD servers

```
1) corp.mycompany.ney
2) mydevenv.net
```

Client machines

```
1) Windows-1
2) Linux-1
```

My **Windows-1** machine is in doamin of **mydevenv.net** and I am also able to log with user-account of **corp.mycompany.net** domain

However I can't do it with **Linux-1** machine.

My **Linux-1** machine is in **mydevenv.net** domain and I am able to login with user-account of mydevenv.net but not with user-account of **corp.mycompmany.net**

Is there any way to do that?

Note - I used Powerbreaker Identity Services (PBIS) to joine Linux-1 machine to Domain

Answer (score 0):

> However I can't do it with Linux-1 machine.

What errors you're getting?

Do the domains have trust? Is the cross-domain trust setup as mutual?

What are the compatibility levels in both domains? If one for example is 2003 and another 2008, then Kerberos tickets validation would be one-way as for example 2008 has more encryption types that 2003 "Function Level" doesn't support/
Read more on this here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/understanding-active-directory-domain-services--ad-ds--functional-levels

You may also need to craft `/etc/krb5.conf` on your Linux server to describe domain controllers for both domains in `realms` and/or `domain_realm` sections.

Comment: Yes, Domains have trust. Below are the logs `May 29 23:40:00 mydm sshd[2110]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.15.12  user=itadmin
May 29 23:40:02 mydm sshd[2106]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for itadmin from 192.168.15.12`